# Prove existance of orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ consisting of eigenvectors of generalized eigenvalue equation

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, orthogonal-matrices, generalized-eigenvector

**Context**

I am studying normal modes oscillations and normal modes [1,2]. In an earlier post [3], I asked for a proof that the generalized eigenvalue equation in normal-mode analysis has positive eigenvalues. This was proven. At this point, I am seeking a related proof regarding the eigenvectors found in normal-mode analysis. There appears to be a related proof in [5] that shows the same thing that I have shown here.

**Question**

How can the following proposition be proved?

> Proposition. Given two  real, symmetric, and positive definite  matrices $\mathbf{T}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$, show that there exists an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ consisting of eigenvectors $\mathbf{a}_1$, $\mathbf{a}_2$, and $\mathbf{a}_3,$ of the generalized eigenvalue equation
> $$\mathbf{V}\,\mathbf{a} = \lambda\,\mathbf{T}\,\mathbf{a}.$$
> Here each eigenvalue represented by $\lambda$ is positive [3].

**My attempt of a proof**

Just like in [3], I can rewrite the  generalized eigenvalue equation
$$\mathbf{V}\,\mathbf{a} = \lambda\,\mathbf{T}\,\mathbf{a}.\tag{1}$$
as an actual eigenvalue equation.
First, by  $\mathbf{w}$ I denote the vector defined by the equation
$$\mathbf{w}= \mathbf{T}^{1/2}\,\mathbf{a} ,$$
and next I rewrite [1] as
$$ \left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{V}
\,\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)^{-1}\,\mathbf{w}  = \lambda \,\mathbf{w}.\tag{2}$$
As in [3], I note that since
$$\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{V}
\,\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)^{-1} = \left(\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{V}
\,\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)^{-1} \right)^T,$$
therefore,
$$\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{V}
\,\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)^{-1} $$ is symmetric.

I now apply the spectral theorem. Since $\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{V}
\,\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)^{-1} $ is Hermitian (and more over positive definite) on $\mathbb{R}^3$, then there exists an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ consisting of eigenvectors of $\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{V}
\,\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)^{-1} $. Each eigenvalue is real (and moreover positive).
I can, therefore, construct a matrix $\mathbf{W}$ defined by the equation
$$ \mathbf{W}= \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{w}_1&\mathbf{w}_2&\mathbf{w}_3\end{bmatrix}.$$
I know that $\mathbf{W}$  is an orthogonal matrix.

Next, I define a new matrix $\mathbf{A}$ by the equation
$$\mathbf{A} = {\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)}^{-1}\mathbf{W} .$$
Next, I try exploit the properties of orthogonal matrices and real symmetric positive definite matrices to show that since
$\mathbf{W}$ is an orthogonal matrix and  ${\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)}^{-1}$
real symmetric positive definite matrix that therefore $\mathbf{A}$ is an orthogonal matrix.

From [4], there are three characteristics or orthogonal matrices which I might exploit:

(1) $ \mathbf{W}^\top = \mathbf{W}^{-1}$,

(2) $\mathbf{W}^{-1}= \mathbf{W}^{\dagger} $, where $\dagger$ is conjugate transpose, and

(3) $ \mathbf{W}^{\dagger}\,\mathbf{W} =  \mathbf{W}\,\mathbf{W}^{\dagger} $

From the first characteristic, I find that
\begin{align}
\mathbf{W}^\top &= \mathbf{W}^{-1}
\\
\left({\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)}\,  \mathbf{A} \right)^\top &= \left({\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)}\,  \mathbf{A} \right)^{-1}
\\
\mathbf{A}^\top\,\left({\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)}\,   \right)^\top &= \left(   \mathbf{A} \right)^{-1}
 \left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}  \right)^{-1}
\\
\mathbf{A}^\top\, \left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)    &= \left(   \mathbf{A} \right)^{-1}
 \left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}  \right)^{-1}
\\
\mathbf{A}^\top\,   &= \left(   \mathbf{A} \right)^{-1}
 \left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}  \right)^{-1}
 \left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}  \right)^{-1}
\\
\mathbf{A}^\top\,   &=   \mathbf{A}  ^{-1}
 \mathbf{T}    ^{-1}\tag{3}
\end{align}
Nope, the first characteristic alone does not yield the desired result.

From the second characteristic, I find that
\begin{align}
\mathbf{W}^\dagger &= \mathbf{W}^{-1}
\\
\left({\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)}\,  \mathbf{A} \right)^\dagger &= \left({\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)}\,  \mathbf{A} \right)^{-1}
\\
\mathbf{A}^\dagger\,\left({\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)}\,   \right)^\dagger &= \left(   \mathbf{A} \right)^{-1}
 \left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}  \right)^{-1}
\\
\mathbf{A}^\dagger\,\left({\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)}\,   \right)  &= \left(   \mathbf{A} \right)^{-1}
 \left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}  \right)^{-1}
\\
\mathbf{A}^\dagger &= 
 \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{T} ^{-1}\tag{4}
\end{align}
Nope, the second characteristic alone does not yield the desired result.

From the third characteristic I find that
\begin{align}
\mathbf{W}^{\dagger}\,\mathbf{W} 
&=  
\mathbf{W}\,\mathbf{W}^{\dagger}  
\\
\left({\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)}\,  \mathbf{A} \right)^{\dagger}
\,
\left({\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)}\,  \mathbf{A} \right)
&=  
\left({\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)}\,  \mathbf{A} \right)
\,
\left({\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)}\,  \mathbf{A} \right)^{\dagger}  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\\
\mathbf{A} ^{\dagger}
\left({\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)}  \right)^{\dagger}
\,
\left({\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)}\,  \mathbf{A} \right)
&=  
\left({\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)}\,  \mathbf{A} \right)
\,
  \mathbf{A} ^{\dagger}  
\,
\left({\left(\mathbf{T}^{1/2}\right)} \right)^{\dagger}  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\\
\mathbf{A} ^{\dagger}
\,
\mathbf{T} 
\, 
 \mathbf{A}  
&=  
 \mathbf{T}^{1/2} 
\,  
\mathbf{A} 
\,
\mathbf{A} ^{\dagger}  
\,
\mathbf{T}^{1/2}  \tag{5}
\end{align}
Nope, the third characteristic alone does not yield the desired result.

Let's if the characteristics combine in some useful way. Equations (4) and (5) together give that
$$   \mathbf{T}^{-1} 
=  
 \mathbf{A} 
\,
\mathbf{A} ^{\dagger} \qquad \text{or that}\qquad
 \mathbf{A} ^{\dagger}
\,
\mathbf{T} 
\, 
 \mathbf{A}  
 =  
\mathbf{I} \,.\tag{6}
  $$
Next, substituting Equation (3) into Equation (6), we find that
$$    \mathbf{A}^\top
=  
\mathbf{A} ^{\dagger} \qquad \text{or that}\qquad
 \mathbf{A} ^{\dagger}
\,
\mathbf{T} 
\, 
 \mathbf{A}  
 =  
\mathbf{I} \,.\tag{7}
  $$
Finally, combining the results in Equation (7) we have that
$$  \boxed{ 
\mathbf{A} ^{\top}
\,
\mathbf{T} 
\, 
 \mathbf{A}  
 =  
\mathbf{I} \,.}
  $$
In conclusion, I find that, in general, given two  real, symmetric, and positive definite  matrices $\mathbf{T}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the standard inner product $\left<y,x\right> = y^\dagger\,x$,  there does not, in fact appear to, exists an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ consisting of eigenvectors $\mathbf{a}_1$, $\mathbf{a}_2$, and $\mathbf{a}_3,$ of the generalized eigenvalue equation
$$\mathbf{V}\,\mathbf{a} = \lambda\,\mathbf{T}\,\mathbf{a}.$$

**Discussion**

Perhaps if the inner product is defined otherwise, then we might be able to construct an affirmative proof.
For example, perhaps if I incorporated, "the general form of an inner product on $\mathbb{C}^3$, [which] is known as the Hermitian form and is given by
$$\left<x, y\right> = y^\dagger\,\mathbf{T}\,x= \overline{x^\dagger\,\mathbf{T}\,y},\,[6]"$$
then I would be able to prove existence of orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of generalized eigenvalue equation. I leave this question open and hope that one more knowledgeable than I might construct an affirmative proof.

**Bibliography**

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mode

[2] Goldstein, "Classical Mechanics," 3rd edition, page 242-3.

[3] [Prove that the generalized eigenvalue equation in normal mode analysis has positive eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4578294/prove-that-the-generalized-eigenvalue-equation-in-normal-mode-analysis-has-posit)

[4] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Matrix_properties

[5] [orthonormal vectors in generalized eigenvalue problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3603279/orthonormal-vectors-in-generalized-eigenvalue-problem?rq=1)

[6] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space